# Different files and gradle android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a project where I need to generate two versions. 
One pointing to development servers and the other to production servers. The previous developers created a configuration file .properties there they have the endpoints set up. 
My questions is. How can I modify or generate the two versions with Android Studio. I know about the flavors and build types, but is there a way to keep lets say two .properties files and the compiler use them in each case.

Best regards

Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Gradle flavors. In a nutshell, it allows you to include different resources in different build-time variations (flavors).

In your `build.gradle`,

```
android {
  productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
    }
    flavor2 {
    }
  }
}
```

This will create two different APKS, one for each flavor. Now, in your src tree,

```
src\
  main\
  flavor1\
  flavor2\
```

Now for example if your `.properties` file was stored as an asset, you'd have `src/flavor1/assets/foo.properties` and `src/flavor2/assets/foo.properties`.

You can also include different source files, and Android manifests. The directory structure under the flavor folder is the same as you'd find in `main` and can contain all of the same resources.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I could not understand well your answer. The .properties is inside assets and that assets have a bunch of other files. Do I have to duplicate them all right?  Is there anything I have to change in .gradle? or the build will automatically know according to the name what directory will use.

Comment: ohh.. is this http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html?  The Build Variant section?